# vagrant up stopped working after windows 10 update

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, windows-10

After a recent Windows 10 update my vagrant virtual machines stopped working, refusing to start at `vagrant up`. The problem seems to be linked to the Virtualbox provider I use for my VMs, and arises only if a private_network is configured in the Vagrantfile, while both port forwarding and `public_network` seem to work.

I already experienced a similar problem the first time I updated my operating system from Windows 7 to Windows 10. In that case, I solved the issue with the patch at Virtualbox's [ticket 14040](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14040); after applying the new windows update, though, the patch solution no longer works.

I also tried to update both VirtualBox and Vagrant to their latest versions, but this didn't change anything.

Here are my Windows / Virtualbox / Vagrant versions:

```
Microsoft Windows 10 version 1511 (build SO 10586.14)
VirtualBox version 5.0.10 r104061
Vagrant version 1.7.4
```

This is the error I get when launching `vagrant up`:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

And the following is the error shown by Virtualbox when trying to start the VM from the Virtualbox User Interface:

```
Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #15' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).

Codice 'uscita: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Componente: 
ConsoleWrap
Interfaccia: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Finally, here the relevant parts of my Vagrantfile; as mentioned, if I comment the `private_network` line, the machine starts:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu-14.04-amd64-docker"
      config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/jose-lpa/packer-ubuntu_14.04/releases/download/v2.0/ubuntu-14.04.box"
      config.vm.hostname = "falcon.staging"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.114"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.gui = false
        vb.memory = "2048"
    end
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. Solution found on this blog helped:
http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=329

Basically, after the update, Windows "magically" turned off *VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver* from VirtualBox Host-Only Network.

To fix it You should check Your network interfaces in Windows:

- In VirtualBox Host-Only Network properties please check if VirtualBox
  NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver is ticked.
- If not - tick it :)

Go check if this helps, I bet it will ;)

Comment: You can edit answers (and questions) by pressing the `edit` button below the answer(question). Please edit the information in there.

Comment: Thank you. I lost 24 hours of development because of this issue.

Comment: if the option is already ticked, as was in my case after the Windows 10 anniversary update (1607), you can try reinstalling VirtualBox. it's not enough to update it, you have to uninstall it and install a new version. [see here](http://www.kublermdk.com/2016/08/09/windows-10-anniversary-update-broke-vagrant/)

Comment: In my case "switching off" and then "on" the connection used by the machine did the trick - in windows network connections

Answer (score 3):

> Go to "Control Panel" -> "Network and Internet" -> "Network Connections"
>
> Right Click on "VirtualBox Host-Only Network #4" -> properties.

This is the window you'll see.

[image]

Now there are 2 options, either "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver" is checked or not.
If it's not, you can just check it and it will do the trick.
But if it's checked you'll need to reinstall your VirtualBox version.